# what does "env -i bash" in a linux shell do?

Tags: bash

I just had a computer science lab where the focus was to create buffer overflow attacks. For one of the labs it was important that I considered environment variables and a few googles later I found that one can use env -i bash to what I assume unset a lot of environment variables? The problem is that I lost the stackoverflow thread which mentioned this and I am yet to find it. So instead I am asking you now. What does env -i bash do?

Comment: What does the documentation (`man env`) say about the `-i` option?

Answer (score 0):

https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/env.1.html

See the man page. The `-i` option starts a fresh clean environment. This would run a new bash shell with no environment variables set.